# Spring MVC - how to display all IDs from database in JSP select form?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I got a problem with displaying all IDs from my database in JSP select form. How should I do it properly? I tried to do something, but this code doesn't work:

Info.jsp:

```
<select name="id" style="font-size: 20; width:120px; height: 670px" name="id" multiple>
    <c:forEach var="patients" items="patientList">
    <option id="idpatient"></option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

InfoController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/informations.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView infoPatient(@ModelAttribute("idpatient") Patient patient, List<Patient> patientList, Model model) throws SQLException{

    setAppContext();

    clinicService.getAllpatients(patientList, patient);

    model.addAttribute("patients", patientList);

    ModelAndView inf = new ModelAndView("InformationsAboutPatient");
    return inf;

}
```

PatientDAOImpl:

```
public void getAllpatients(List<Patient> patientList, Patient patient) throws SQLException{

    String query = "SELECT idpatient FROM virtualclinic.patient";
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);         
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()){
            patient.setId(rs.getString(1));

            patientList.add(patient);
        }
```

ClinicServiceImpl:

```
public void getAllpatients(List<Patient> patientList, Patient patient) throws SQLException{
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("clinicconfig.xml");
    patientDAO = ctx.getBean("patientDAO", PatientDAOImpl.class);

    patient.setId(patient.getId());
    patientList.add(patient);

    patientDAO.getAllpatients(patientList, patient);

}
```

Here is an error:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context   with path [/VirtualClinic] threw exception [Request processing failed;  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:  Failed to instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface]  with root cause
 org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to  instantiate [java.util.List]: Specified class is an interface
at      org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101)
 at   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:106)
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringJDBCExample</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring JDBC Support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Need your build file. This looks like a version issue.

Comment: I meant your POM or Gradle build file.

Comment: @chrylis: ok check now :D

Comment: You're mixing versions 4.0.2 and 4.2.4. You need to use the same version of the Spring components.

Comment: I changed to 4.2.4 and error still appears

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass a `List<Patient>` *into* your controller and then into your DAO to fill, then bubble it back up. This isn't customary in Java; the DAO should create and return a new `List<Patient>`, and you can eliminate the parameter from your controller.

Even better, don't hand-write DAOs. If using JPA doesn't make sense, use the community [Spring Data JDBC repository](https://github.com/nurkiewicz/spring-data-jdbc-repository), which does your DAO operations for you automatically.